# clicking a link in jqueryui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery dialog for displaying html files in a modal dialog:

main site calling test.html:

```
<body>
<div id="layer" style="display: none;">
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#layer").dialog({
          dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff',
      autoOpen: false,
      position : ['center',20],
      /*draggable: false, */
      resizable : true,
      modal : true,
            show : 'fade',
            hide : /*'drop'*/'fade',
            width: 'auto',
            heigth: 'auto',
            open: function() {
             $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');
      },

   });

  $( function() {
      $("#layer").load('test.php', function() {
          $("#layer").dialog("open");
      });
    });

</script>
```

This works fine and the content of test.php is displayed well. But when i'm clicking a link in test.php the link is opened in the whole browser windows. How i can display the new site in the dialog too?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have the answer in front of you! You need to `load` the new URL into the `dialog`.

Comment: Add an iframe in dialog and then open url in it.

Answer (score 0):

Load the content of new url to the dialog.

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".yourLinkCssClassName", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function (data) {
            $("#layer").html(data);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. this works. Unfortunately the layer doesn't fit in width and height when a new page is loaded on this way. And what also not works is to load content from other websites in this dialog (e.g. http://google.de). My first attempt was with an iframe, but with iframe i had also the problem with height and width. Actually I really want an iframe, because i want to load in the modal dialog standalone pages that have nothing to do with the caller page. Is there any possibility automatically fixing width and height maybe with a maximum?